# Inclusive term for alcohol, coffee and tobacco?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology

I am looking for a word that can be used to describe alcoholic beverages, coffee and tobacco products collectively. The closest I can think of is "drug," but that is too broad. Namely, it includes other substances that are not nearly as widely socially and legally accepted, as well as some forms of medicine.

Comment: Are you asking about alcoholic beverages, coffee, and tobacco products in general, certain types of those things (hard liquor, cigarettes), or specifically the chemical components: ethanol, caffeine, and nicotine?

Comment: Related: [What is a word that encompasses drugs, supplements, and foods?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262398/what-is-a-word-that-encompasses-drugs-supplements-and-foods)

Comment: I am almost certain that a similar question was asked in the past but I could not find it in the archives, perhaps it was deleted. Why does it have to be a single word? Could you please edit your question and explain? I'd be tempted to suggest *vices* but that would also include gambling, eating sweets, junkfood, etc. *Beverage* would exclude tabacco. *Toxins* is too broad and misleading...

Comment: @miltonaut Beverages, coffee, and tobacco products in general. I edited my question as you suggested.

Comment: _Pick-me-ups_ might do... or it might sound completely wrong. More context would help, with maybe a fill-in-the-blank example sentence for your intended use.

Comment: What's wrong with "legal drugs"? They are drugs and they are legal. There's no single word that encompasses only these three substances without also including other substances (ie. coffee does not intoxicate; alcohol does not stimulate, and "drugs" has the connotation of "illegal drugs")

Comment: Basic essentials works.

Comment: Is tea included?

Comment: Possibly suitable legal jargon would be "non-controlled psychoactive substances", although that would include all manner of legal highs, uncommon and taboo, as well as the socially acceptable and innocuous. To narrow it down to the Big Three you mention, maybe "common non-controlled psychoactive substances". But that's a mouthful, somewhat suggestive of dodgy fake headshop weed... and definitely _not_ a single word. "Licit intoxicants" might do. Not a single word, though. (I doubt you'll get one word that works; you should probably amend your question to allow phrases and give more context.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have it, it's a bit of a cheat but it would comprehend substances such as caffeine, nicotine, and ethanol. It is normally written as two words, [legal stimulants](https://www.irishexaminer.com/lifestyle/features/humaninterest/students-turning-to-legal-stimulants-for-exam-edge-230722.html), but by adding a hyphen you can make it into a compound word.

**legal-stimulants**

> [Stimulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimulant) (also often referred to as psychostimulants or colloquially as uppers) **is an overarching term that covers many drugs** including those that increase activity of the central nervous system and the body, drugs that are pleasurable and invigorating, or drugs that have [sympathomimetic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sympathomimetic) effects.
>   <sub>Wikipedia</sub>

**EDIT**

@James McLeod correctly pointed out, in the comments below, that alcohol is classified as a [depressant](https://www.michaelshouse.com/alcohol-treatment/why-is-alcohol-called-a-depressant/). Despite its name, a depressant does not make a person feel depressed, it is a substance which slows a person's physical and psychological responses. Therefore, if the OP is writing for a medical or an academic journal, the expression "legal-stimulant" would be completely erroneous.

On the one hand, the consumption of alcohol and cigarettes is often called a *[**vice**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/vice)* but on the other hand, it would exclude coffee and tea despite both containing the stimulant caffeine.

**Addictive-substances** might be a possible solution, seeing as all four *drugs* are addictive but just like the term “drug” itself, an addictive substance would also include narcotics: tranquilizers, sedatives, stupefacients, etc.

Comment: I think alcohol is the opposite, a depressant.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod sigh...damn, I hadn't thought of that. I was thinking of "pleasurable and invigorating" What about a single drink?

Comment: +1 Not as snappy but maybe _legal intoxicants_ would help with your alcohol problem! That hyphenated form seems a bit odd to me. It does occur, does it?

Comment: @tmgr you can post it as an answer, explaining that alcohol isn't a stimulant. I wouldn't object at all.

Comment: The hyphenation feels wrong. It changes the meaning. A legal-stimulant would be something that stimulates 'legal [things]' or 'legals'

Comment: @Mari-LouA no thanks, I’m spoken for.

Comment: :-) couldn’t resist, sorry.

Comment: -1 Alcohol is not a stimulant. Also "addictive stubstances" and "legal stimulants" (depending on local laws) both include some much harder drugs.

Comment: @Richard erm, I said as much in the edit and in the comments. I'm not denying anything. But the OP accepted my answer, and I cannot delete it now. So write a good answer, explaining to the OP why they should not accept this solution.

Comment: I'm with @AaronF on this one; a hyphenation is not appropriate here. It would work in his instance, or in a phrase where it becomes a compound adjective like "a legal-stimulant binge," though not on its own.

Comment: Regardless, your answer still "legal-stimulants" and that is incorrect. @copcurry's decision to mark it as correct is misguided and should be reconsidered.

Comment: The hyphenated version simply does not exist. I suggest you remove it from your answer.

Comment: Oh dear, I said right at the beginning it was `a bit of a cheat`. And no one is writing any answers despite my encouragements. I've been open, I've been honest and I've explained in the edit very clearly why my initial response was faulty. Can't do more than that. My advice to everyone? **Write a better answer** or ***upvote microenzo's answer*** And comment as much as you like. Everything I needed to say and do I have.

Comment: 'intoxicant' is only appropriate for tobacco and coffee in the most metaphorical of situations. 'stimulant' works for those two, and contrary to the others, I think works for alcohol; even though it is not medically the correct technical term, 'stimulant is still used for alcohol outside of medicine.

Comment: The hyphen, however, is like throwing tacks into a balloon party.

Comment: @Mari-LouA With respect, if it's not valid English then it shouldn't be submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Legal recreational drugs

I assume that it is acceptable to use a term which includes tea, as well as coffee. Trying to find a term which includes one popular caffeinated hot drink and not another one will be completely impossible.

Alcohol, tobacco and caffeine are legal in most places. Alcohol is illegal in some Muslim countries, but they generally don't use English as their main language.

What sets them apart from other legal drugs is that they are used recreationally. This means the term doesn't include things like painkillers.

Some places will have other legal recreational drugs which are harder than alcohol, tobacco and caffeine. In the UK, all recreational drugs are illegal except a few whitelisted drugs (notably alcohol, tobacco and caffeine), so the term is very accurate in the UK.

Elsewhere, you could use the word "soft", i.e. "**legal soft drugs**" to indicate that hard drugs like Mephedrone (probably illegal most places now, just an example) are not included. Describing drugs as hard or soft is generally only done with recreational drugs, so using it with "recreational" would be redundant.

Comment: Not one word though, is it?

Comment: And when has  coffee ever been described as a recreational drug?

Comment: @Mari-LouA This conveys the meaning in the fewest words possible which is the best that you can hope for when looking at such a specific set of substances.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Here's an article which refers to coffee specifically as a recreational drug. It may be very formal, but it's not wrong. https://www.sciencealert.com/new-discovery-coffee-affects-steroid-endocannabinoid-metabolites

Answer (score 0):

If you are concentrating on the effects on the nervous system, **psychoactive substances** are substances which act on the nervous system in a stimulating or depressing way. As an example of usage, this is the legal definition in the UK:

http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/2/section/2/enacted

Notice that the *legal* definition in those pages explicitly excludes alcohol, coffee and tobacco, but you can infer the wider meaning from the text.

Comment: Actually the bill applies to those substances which are not covered by legal classification at all. That means it doesn't apply to coffee etc because they are explicitly legal. "psychoactive substances" in the UK would often be understood as legalese for "former legal highs", which is what this legislation is meant to ban.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - the *legal* definition of psychoactive substances excludes the exempted substances, but I was describing the fact that the definition in 2.1.a seems to cover the question (albeit not in a single word, I must admit....)

Comment: I'd delete the reference to the UK Psychoactive Substances Act 2016 altogether, or else distinguish it as a very unwieldy, counterintuitive and technical definition.

Comment: I agree with the good point made, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the context in which you want to use the word you're looking for, here are some other (generally informal) choices:

1. What's your *poison*?

> - used to ask someone what they would like to drink.
> - https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What%27s+your+poison%3f

2. What's your *drug of choice*?

> - 3. By extension, any habit, activity, or vice that one is particularly fond of or dependent upon.
> - https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Drug+of+choice

3. What's your *high*?

> - n. a state of euphoria caused by drugs or alcohol.
> - https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/High

4. What's your *guilty pleasure*?

> - Something that one enjoys or finds pleasurable but knows or feels to be bad, inferior, aberrant, or lowbrow, especially as might be perceived or judged by other people.
> - https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Guilty+pleasure

The first three would be specific enough for the items you're asking about (though the third one is generally more for illegal substances), while the fourth is more general and broad, and could include a whole gamut of pleasures and vices from the substances you mentioned to binging episodes of *The Real Housewives* while listening to 90's boy bands (none of which are my guilty pleasures, I swear ).